# How to set the font-size of the text writed in WYSIWYG

Tags: php, joomla, fonts, wysiwyg

After the text is submitted and saved in the database, then I get it and put to the page, but the problem is that the size of the font can be big or very big. However I need to set the font-size equal, not depending of the font-size used in the WYSIWYG, but I don't understand why the font-size isn't changing?

For example I have this:

```
<div style="font-size: 10pt">
<p>
BIG TEXT    
</p>
</div>
```

The `<P>` - is the text rendered from the WYSIWYG, and my style doesn't work, I also have tried to set !important - also don't work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you supply a _full_ example i.e. including the text from the WYSIWYG editor? At the moment, there is not enough info to answer this question.

Comment: By the way, when asking questions, if you could take a minute to check the formatting and spelling, it is generally widely appreciated. It's fine if English isn't your first language - just use the spell-checker in your browser's edit box. Doesn't need to be perfect, but better readability = more answers `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should add the `font-size` declaration to the `<div>` but to the `<p>` tag. another option is to add a piece of css into the header of your page like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            size: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u use like this .... whatever words using in p tag those all are get font size is 10 ...

```
 <div>
<p style="size='10px'";>
BIG TEXT    
</p>
```